# VBA: Creating a PivotTable on New Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create a PivotTable on a separate sheet from the data source. The problem I'm having is creating the PivotTable on a separate page from the PivotCache as I get the Run-Time error '1004' whereas I can paste the PivotTable on the same sheet no problem. The code I currently have looks like this:

```
    Sub PivotTable()

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FG REPORT").Activate

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pf2 As PivotField
Dim pf3 As PivotField


Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
                                        SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                        SourceData:=Sheet4.Name & "!" & Sheet4.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, _
                                        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot")
ws.Activate
Cells.Select
Cells.Clear
Range("A1").Select


Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=ActiveCell, _
    TableName:="AgedPivot")


'Set Pivot Field variables

Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Description")
Set pf2 = pt.PivotFields("Age Range")
Set pf3 = pt.PivotFields("OH Qtys")

pf.Orientation = xlRowField
pf2.Orientation = xlPageField
pf3.Orientation = xlDataField


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try concatenating a single quote before and after the sheet name, as the name contains a space:

```
SourceData:="'" & Sheet4.Name & "'!" & Sheet4.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address
```